# CSS Background image not full-size on some browsers

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm making a little demo thing for my sister's wedding, I basically want to set the body background to a different image as the user scrolls down the page.

[Here is a functioning version of the page.](http://james.is.agoodman.com.au/carla_and_jamie/)

The process itself works fine, however on:

**A desktop mac running Chrome (browser width around 1900px)**

The image does not stretch across the page, although the background remains fixed (as it should).

[Screenshot of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8ax7.jpg)

**A mobile phone (android chrome)**

The background image does not stay fixed (when the user scrolls down, the background image is left behind). Funnily, I cannot reproduce this in my laptop browser by making my window smaller - possibly a limitation with the mobile browser itself?

[Screenshot of this problem](http://imgur.com/jNZBY)

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

Comment: have you tried setting the background size with javascript on page load?

Comment: The background size is already set to `cover`which should have this same effect, no? Also, this wouldn't solve the position-not-being-fixed in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

The image is 1200px wide. So on a 1900 resolution the image doesn't stretch and is smaller :). If you use background-size: 100%; It should stretch.

As for mobile: [This question is the same issue as you with solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011085/keep-image-on-top-while-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

set the

```
width:100%
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

in your image tag or div

if the 100% is not work use px for width